# Add Header Value For Spring TestRestTemplate Integration Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am using `TestRestTemplate` for integration testing on our product.

I have one test that looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testDeviceQuery() {
    ResponseEntity<Page> deviceInfoPage = template.getForEntity(base, Page.class);

    // validation code here
}
```

This particular request expects a Header value. Can someone please let me know how I can add a header to the `TestRestTemplate` call?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want all of your requests using `TestRestTemplate` to include certain headers, you could add the following to your setup:

```
testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().setInterceptors(
        Collections.singletonList((request, body, execution) -> {
            request.getHeaders()
                    .add("header-name", "value");
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }));
```

Answer (score 49):

**Update**: [As of Spring Boot 1.4.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#testresttemplate), [`TestRestTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/web/client/TestRestTemplate.html) does not extend `RestTemplate` anymore but still provides the same API as `RestTemplate`.

`TestRestTemplate` <del>extends `RestTemplate`</del> provides the same API as the `RestTemplate`, so you can use that same API for sending requests. For example:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("your_header", "its_value");
template.exchange(base, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), Page.class);
```

Comment: This solved it, thanks a bunch. Just one part to note is that the `HttpHeaders` needs to be from the `org.springframework.http` package

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use multiple headers for all your requests, you can add the below

```
 import org.apache.http.Header;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
 import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;


 private void setTestRestTemplateHeaders() {
    Header header = new BasicHeader("header", "value");
    Header header2 = new BasicHeader("header2", "value2");
    List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
    headers.add(header);
    headers.add(header2);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(headers).build();
    testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate().setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
 }
```

Once the headers are set you can either use `TestRestTemplate [testRestTemplate]` or `RestTemplate [testRestTemplate.getRestTemplate()]` for your REST calls